# Apply Regex.Replace on many same mark

Tags: c#, regex, string

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "\"aaaaa\"" + "aaaaa" + "\"aaaaa\"" + "aaaaa" + "\"aaaaa\"";
            line = Regex.Replace(line, "\".+\"", "");
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I want get rid of `"aaaaa"` and keep`aaaaa`.

So with this string I should get `aaaaaaaaaa`.

But with the code I get nothing.

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make the `.+` non greedy `.+?`

[Output c#](http://rextester.com/FUZE45527)

Answer (score 0):

I also try it, you should replace `.+ to .+?`

[Sample Code](https://repl.it/@timsky/RegexReplace-on-many-same-mark)